# Why did Queen Ingrith believe that the wounded Maleficent would lash out?

Tags: maleficent, maleficent-mistress-of-evil

In *Maleficent: Mistress of Evil* (2019), Gerda describes to Queen Ingrith about the creature that pulled Maleficent from the depths of the sea:

> Queen Ingrith: What did it look like?
>
> Gerda: Her. It carried her up into the sky.
>
> Queen Ingrith: Hmm. **A wounded animal lashes out** and now she's not
>   alone.

Maleficent never retaliated after being shot by Gerda, why did Queen Ingrith believe that she did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queen Ingrith is resentful against fairies in general due to her past with them.

When she says "A wounded animal lashes out", she is implying that she believes fairies (or atleast just Maleficient) are mere savages, beasts who are dangerous, and just like animals, more dangerous if they're wounded.

It's not about if Maleificient already retaliated in that moment, but if she will do in the future. And well, she was right. Maleificient tried to get revenge later in the story.